# Good source of d and d or similar game, minituare figurines?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons

So I am playing a new group of players and they are hoping for more of a visual aid.

Does anyone know any good places to pick up cheap figures?

Answer (score 1):

**[Reaper Miniatures](https://www.reapermini.com/)**

Reaper Miniatures is a company that deals with a lot of RPGs, and has very good prices for their selection. A lot of the stuff you'd use for D&D 3.5E is found in the Warlord section of their site, which can be found [here](https://www.reapermini.com/Games/Warlord).